# Latent Space and SVD

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I have a fairly large dataset for which I am calculating the SVD on then I want to get back the matrix.  My matrix shape is: (33388, 104) which is a lot of columns and rows.  I want an energy of 80%, which is `k=51`.

When I go to return my matrix in the return, I get the following error:

`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (33388,51) (51,51)`

`img is a numpy array of an image file
k is the number of singular vectors to use`

How can I correct my function to fix this error?

```
def rank_k_approx(img, k):
    """Return a rank-k approximation

    img: an image (as a 2D grayscale array)
    k: number of singular vectors used"""
    u, sigma, vt = np.linalg.svd(img)
    energy = np.linalg.norm(sigma)**2
    approx_energy = np.linalg.norm(sigma[:k])**2
    percentage = approx_energy*100/energy
    print ("Energy retained = %4.2f"%percentage)
    return u[:,:k]*np.diag(sigma[:k])*vt[:k,:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs of `np.linalg.svd` are `ndarray` objects, for which the operator `*` is element-wise multiplication. You want to compute the matrix product, for which you need to use `np.dot()` or the `@` operator.

The multiplication should be:

```
u[:, :k].dot(np.diag(sigma[:k])).dot(vt[:k])
```

Comment: Actually I don't think this gives what I need, the shape is still (33388, 104), shouldn't it be smaller after the multiplication?

Comment: @codebase5000 No. You're making a rank-k approximation to your original matrix, where `k` is the rank required to recover 80% of the variance of the original matrix. This is a low-rank approximation to the original matrix, but it has the same size as the original. It's just [rank-deficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions).

Comment: I just realized that after I hit enter sorry about that.